# Changing and creating files in .NET Core folder

Tags: iis, .net-core

for example, there is an application written using dot net core 2.1

Published under the IIS (Windows Server 2016). At the root of the application (near to the binaries (.dll)) random files are being created and modified. Will this affect the performance of the application? Will it make a difference if these files are created in a subdirectory next to the binaries?

If we exclude IIS and host under Kestrel, will it affect somehow?

As far as I remember, when hosting applications, written on a .NET fullframework, under IIS, and modifying any file (for example, a text file) in the BIN directory resulted in restarting the web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what files are being created and modified i would separate them form the app files for security reasons to say the least. Having said that to answer your question.

It should not affect the performance unless the volume of operations is so large that it will use up all iops on the drive or the pc/ram of the machine.

Kestrel will not be affected unless you try to modify files that kestrel uses for the app in some way and if you use `dotnet watch run` it will try to recompile them and run in the host if not it will ignore their existence until the host is restarted.

IIS should ignore them as well but i do not know what will happen if you have those files in bin and try to restart the host. i have tried changing and adding a file and did not restart. Maybe there is something in IIS settings but since i have not setup our IIS my answer is lacking in that regard.